# My Mongo query is too large and I'm reaching a memory issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm reaching some sort of RAM limit when doing this query, here's the error:

```
The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query

  @length=100

  @request_id=962

  @response_to=0

  @op_code=2004

  @flags=[]

  @full_collection_name="test_db.cases"

  @skip=1650

  @limit=150

  @selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{"created_at"=>1}}

  @fields=nil>

failed with error 17144: "Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33555783 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes"


See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md

for details about this error.
```

There are two solutions I can think of:

1) up the buffer limit. this requires mongo 2.8 which is some unstable release that i'd have to install manually.

2) break apart the query? chunk it? this is what the query looks like:

upload_set = Case.all.order_by(:created_at.asc).skip(@set_skipper).limit(150).each_slice(5).to_a

@set_skipper grows by 150 every time the method is called.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

> Sorted Documents
>
> MongoDB will only return sorted results on fields without an index if
>   the combined size of all documents in the sort operation, plus a small
>   overhead, is less than 32 megabytes.

Did you try using an index on created_at ? That should remove that limitation.